# NodeJs npm start is not working

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I got that error while running the nodejs app using npm over both mac os x and linux debian x64.

I installed node_modules using "npm install".

How could I solve such a problem ?

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.0
3 info using node@v4.4.2
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb@1.0.0
6 info start ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb@1.0.0
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb@1.0.0 Failed to exec start script
9 verbose stack Error: ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
9 verbose stack Exit status 1
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous>             (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:217:16)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous>     (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:24:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
9 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
9 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:827:16)
9 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
10 verbose pkgid ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb@1.0.0
11 verbose cwd /Users/mostafakhattab/Documents/gcloud/ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb
12 error Darwin 15.4.0
13 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
14 error node v4.4.2
15 error npm  v2.15.0
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 error ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
17 error Exit status 1
18 error Failed at the ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb@1.0.0 start script     'node app.js'.
18 error This is most likely a problem with the ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb package,
18 error not with npm itself.
18 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
18 error     node app.js
18 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
18 error     npm bugs ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb
18 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
18 error
18 error     npm owner ls ibtikar-staging-smart-bulb
18 error There is likely additional logging output above.
19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: npm just print out exactly what you should do start from the 18 error.